# How to format date inside source script?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm using `terms` aggregations with `script` property, i know that i can use `format` property to get date value in specific date format; but i wanna write required format to be gotten inside script source code.

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "NAME": {
      "terms": {
        "script": {
          "source": "doc['Ship Date'].value",
          "lang": "painless"
        },
        "size": 100,
        "order": {
          "_key": "asc"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like below

```
"size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "NAME": {
      "terms": {
        "script": {
          "source": "String datetime = 'Thu, 13 Oct 1983 22:15:30 GMT';ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse(datetime,DateTimeFormatter.RFC_1123_DATE_TIME); return zdt ",
          "lang": "painless"
        },
        "size": 100,
        "order": {
          "_key": "asc"
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

You can parse different formats to ZonedDateTime.parse()
You can get full detail [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/painless/current/painless-datetime.html)

Comment: Glad could be of help.